# Deleting an element from a linked list

Tags: c, linked-list

I have some issues with deleting an element from a given linked list. Here's what I've got:

```
void deleteElement(node *list)
{
    node *currP, *prevP = NULL;

    for (currP = list; currP != NULL; prevP = currP, currP = currP->next) {

        if(currP->info.name[0] == 'A') {  /* Found it. */
            if (prevP == NULL) {
                list = currP->next;
            } else {
                prevP->next = currP->next;
            }

            free(currP);
            return;
        }
    }
    printList(list);
}
```

Written in that way the printList function prints me the whole list and it's like nothing had been deleted. Any ideas on what's wrong?

Comment: `list = currP->next;` is important, as it is meaningless to the *caller*. the value of list, a pointer, is just that; a *value*. You need to either pass the pointer by address (a pointer to pointer) or utilize the otherwise unused return result to always return the list head and utilize it accordingly.

Comment: You should not try to do linked list in C before understand C basic.

Answer (score 0):

First: It seems that no element for the deletion was found. If it was found the `return` statement would end the function and the `printList(list)` function would not be called.

Second: Use `break` to jump out of the `for` loop instead of `return`.

Third: your `deleteElement()` should return the pointer to `list` for that case you `free` the first element. Then, inside the function the list is set to the new first element but if you don't return the new address your list is just a freed element and could cause a segmentation fault when you call the element the next time.